# How to install adobe flash for Chromium

Tags: flash, chromium, adobe

is there any way to install adobe flash player for chromium, so that I will be able to use chromium properly?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Close Chromium
2. Install the Pepper Flash package with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
   ```
3. Open Chromium.

Comment: ... or install Google Chrome, which already comes with Pepper Flash